# How to show textbox or label in a Protovis line chart?

Tags: charts, textbox, label, linechart, protovis

I am creating a Railway Time Table Line Chart. In X-axis shows the Time & Y-axis shows the Station Names. This line-graph showing a train is going from the source station to the destination station, and the train stops some stations that is showing by a DOT with a Tooltip displaying the Train Name + Station Name + Time.

The graph is all fine, but I want to the show a box with train name at the beginning of each train from where the train is starting. I have attached the screen shot of the graph for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Sup, have you tried the tipsy plugin?

You can change the envent that triggers it.